# Where can I find historical exchange rate data for Dash (ex DarkCoin)/USD?

Tags: exchanges, database, dash

Is there a public data provider that allows to download the full history of Dash (ex DarkCoin) vs. US Dollar exchange rates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/dash/#charts) provide charts since February 2014 and IIRC, the name was Darkcoin back then. It include the price in both Satoshi & USD.

Comment: Thank you. But how do you get the data into a CSV/XLS file? The API provides just last values, not the full history as far as I knew.

Comment: It's only possible to export it as PNG, PDF, JPG , SVG vector image or simply print it. You could do so using the button on the top right of the chart.